# Custom UITableViewCell is wrong width on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

I've created a custom `UITableViewCell`, but when I run my app on iPad the cell's content is the same width as on iPhone. I want the content - the background `UIView` for example - to be the complete width.

**customCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface customCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *background;

@end
```

**customCell.m**

```
#import "customCell.h"

@implementation customCell

@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize description = _description;
@synthesize background = _background;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // configure background
        self.background = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, 115.0f)];

        // configure title
        self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, self.contentView.frame.size.width-10, 70)];
        self.title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
        self.title.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        self.title.numberOfLines = 4;
        self.title.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 20;
        self.title.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        self.title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular" size:16];

        [self.background addSubview:self.title];

        // configure description
        self.description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 80, self.contentView.frame.size.width-10, 20)];
        self.description.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.description.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        self.description.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Bold" size:13];

        [self.background addSubview:self.description];

        [self addSubview:self.background];
        [self sendSubviewToBack:self.background];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cell's size is not yet set in the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method. Either setup your subviews with proper `autoresizingMask` values or implement the cell's `layoutSubviews` method to update their sizes.

Also, since you add the `title` and `description` labels to the `background` view, the labels' sizes should be based on the size of the `background` view, not the size of the cell's `contentView`.

And lastly, never name a property `description`. It will conflict with the `description` method inherited from `NSObject`.